# Nom parser fails to not consume invalid input

Tags: rust, nom

My test `parse_line_repeat` is crashing in the last line (which is invalid to such point) instead of returning it as a remainder as show in the test itself.

I have tried using `tuple` instead of `pair` and `many0` instead of `many1`, the first got solved by [this blogpost on nom](https://blog.adamchalmers.com/nom-chars) and the second after reading again the [documentation on choosing a combinator](https://github.com/rust-bakery/nom/blob/main/doc/choosing_a_combinator.md).

What I want to do may be described as error recovery, but by this [article](https://eyalkalderon.com/blog/nom-error-recovery/) says otherwise, thus I am out of ideas of for what search.

Here is the `lib.rs`

```rust
use nom::{
    branch::alt,
    bytes::complete::tag,
    character::complete::space0,
    multi::{many1, many_till},
    sequence::pair,
    IResult,
};

fn parse_token(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, bool> {
    let (remaining, token) = alt((tag("0"), tag("1")))(input)?;
    if token == "1" {
        return Ok((remaining, true));
    } else {
        return Ok((remaining, false));
    }
}

#[allow(dead_code)]
fn parse_line(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, Vec<bool>> {
    let (remaining, (tokens_raw, _)) = pair(
        many1(many_till(space0, parse_token)),
        many_till(space0, tag("\n")),
    )(input)?;

    let mut tokens = Vec::new();

    for (_, token) in tokens_raw {
        let token: bool = token;
        tokens.push(token);
    }

    Ok((remaining, tokens))
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn parse_token_test() {
        assert_eq!(parse_token("0"), Ok(("", false)));
        assert_eq!(parse_token("1"), Ok(("", true)));
    }

    #[test]
    fn parse_line_test() {
        assert_eq!(parse_line("1 \n"), Ok(("", vec![true])));
        assert_eq!(parse_line("0 \n"), Ok(("", vec![false])));
        assert_eq!(
            parse_line("1 1 1 1\n"),
            Ok(("", vec![true, true, true, true]))
        );
    }

    #[test]
    fn parse_line_repeat() {
        let rtn = parse_line("1 \n 1\n");
        assert_eq!(rtn, Ok((" 1\n", vec![true])));
        let rtn = parse_line(rtn.unwrap().0);
        assert_eq!(rtn, Ok(("", vec![true])));
        let rtn = parse_line("1\n 1\n\n");
        assert_eq!(rtn, Ok((" 1\n\n", vec![true])));
        let rtn = parse_line(rtn.unwrap().0);
        assert_eq!(rtn, Ok(("\n", vec![true])));
        let rtn = parse_line(rtn.unwrap().0);
        assert_eq!(rtn, Ok(("\n", vec![])));
    }    
}
```

Here is the `Cargo.toml`

```ini
[package]
name = "minimal"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
name = "minimal"
path = "src/lib.rs"

[dependencies]
nom = "7.1.3"
```

Error:

```
$ cargo test
    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.94s
     Running unittests minimal/main.rs

running 3 tests
test tests::parse_line_test ... ok
test tests::parse_token_test ... ok
test tests::parse_line_repeat ... FAILED

failures:

---- tests::parse_line_repeat stdout ----
thread 'tests::parse_line_repeat' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `Err(Error(Error { input: "\n", code: ManyTill }))`,
 right: `Ok(("\n", []))`', minimal/main.rs:67:9
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace


failures:
    tests::parse_line_repeat

test result: FAILED. 2 passed; 1 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s

error: test failed, to rerun pass `--lib`
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b37ce0618df611bcffb59e4d4104feae)

Comment: @JohnKugelman Here is https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b37ce0618df611bcffb59e4d4104feae

Comment: It's not mysterious at all you explicitly require at least one token to be present (`many1`), since there is none the parser fails.

Comment: How do you want it to behave? Why should the last one return a `"\n"` newline? Shouldn't it parse that line, returning `Ok(("", []))`? It is very unusual that a parser **succeeds** without consuming anything. So in my eyes, this should either fail, or return `Ok(("", []))`, which is exactly what `many1` and `many0` do, respectively.

Comment: I have very strong [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) feelings here.

Comment: @Finomnis Maybe? I have a later test where I have multiple blocks of lines with end and start keywords, and fails when there is more than one block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the real reason is that your tests / expected behavior is flawed.

Reworded in simpler terms, your last test checks the following behavior for `parse_line`:

- `1 \n 1\n` ->  `1\n` + `[true]`
- `1\n` -> `<empty>` + `[true]`

Then, you check:

- `1\n 1\n\n` ->  `1\n\n` + `[true]`
- `1\n\n` -> `\n` + `[true]`

And finally:

- `\n` -> `\n` + `[]`.

That last one doesn't make much sense to me. If  `1\n` should become `<empty>`, then why should `\n` not also become `<empty>`? Why does one consume the newline, and the other doesn't? If it is because an empty line without `1`s should not be consumed by the parser, then why is it wrong that it returns an error? Returning an error is what is expected of a parser that cannot consume an object.

So the possible ways you could go are:

- An empty line (`\n`) **is not** consumable by your code. In that case your code is already correct and the test is flawed, and should expect an error instead.
- An empty line (`\n`) **is** consumable by your code. In that case both your code and the test are flawed. The code should be `many0` instead of `many1` and the test should check for `Ok(("", vec![]))` at the end.

Your original code kind of indicates that you would like the empty line to **not** be consumed. In that case, I would modify the test to:

```rust
#[test]
fn parse_line_repeat() {
    let rtn = parse_line("1 \n 1\n");
    assert_eq!(rtn, Ok((" 1\n", vec![true])));
    let rtn = parse_line(rtn.unwrap().0);
    assert_eq!(rtn, Ok(("", vec![true])));
    let rtn = parse_line("1\n 1\n\n");
    assert_eq!(rtn, Ok((" 1\n\n", vec![true])));
    let rtn = parse_line(rtn.unwrap().0);
    assert_eq!(rtn, Ok(("\n", vec![true])));
    let rtn = parse_line(rtn.unwrap().0);
    assert_eq!(
        rtn,
        Err(nom::Err::Error(nom::error::Error {
            input: "\n",
            code: nom::error::ErrorKind::ManyTill
        }))
    );
}
```

Comment: How can I add the form the error that is being throwed out by the parser?

Comment: @Delfin I'm not sure I if understand this question :) Would you mind rewording it?

Comment: How can I put the error that is making fail the current test as the assert_eq target?

Comment: @Delfin Edited my answer to include an example

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this instead of immediately failing with `?` in the error case in `parse_line`:

```rust
    let Ok((remaining, (tokens_raw, _))) = pair(
        many1(many_till(space0, parse_token)),
        many_till(space0, tag("\n")),
    )(input) else {
        return Ok((input, Vec::new()))
    };
```

This doesn't hoever do what's written on the can, it doesn't `parse_line` it ignores a line and does nothing instead.

Of course in a more complex scenario you might want to look deeper into the error details, then you'd want to use `match` instead of a simple `let ... else`

Comment: This has the big drawback that if one were to use `parse_line` in a loop, as one probably would when parsing multiple lines, this will livelock.

Comment: Yes like I stated, that behavior makes `parse_line` a misnomer.